# Read the contents of a column several times with Mysql datareader

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

I am creating a console application that outputs the contents of the "password" column and the "username" column. Does anyone know how I could rewrite the output every time new data appears on the password and username rows?

I had thought about recreating the instance every time and to reassign `MySqlDataReader` to `cmd.ExecuteReader()` in this way:

```
for (int a = 0; a == 0;)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Username: " + reader.GetString("username"));
            Console.WriteLine("Password: " + reader.GetString("password") + "\n");
        }
                   
}
```

But that give this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
> in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
> in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
> in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
> in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
> in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
> in showaph.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\utente\source\repos\showaph\Program.cs:riga 51

How could I solve?

This is my full code:

```
namespace showaph
{
    class Program
    {            
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=sql7.freemysqlhosting.net; Port=3306; Database=sql7389377; Uid=sql7389377; Pwd=*******; ");              
                connection.Open();
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected \n");    
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not connected");
                }
                string query = "SELECT * FROM users";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Username: " + reader.GetString("username"));
                        Console.WriteLine("Password: " + reader.GetString("password") + "\n");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read all the rows once into some list or array, then you can (re)access them as you wish via that list or array. And as a side note: It appears you may store passwords as plain text. Don't do that. Salt and hash them.

Comment: @stickybit What do you mean? if I put the password and email values inside two arrays, are they always updated in real time?

Answer (score 0):

you need to close your reader

```cs
using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username: " + reader.GetString("username"));
        Console.WriteLine("Password: " + reader.GetString("password") + "\n");
    }
                   
}
```

Comment: I tried to add your code but it doesn't work

Comment: I updated the code in my question as you suggested yourself. still not working

Comment: @PietroContadini My code is correct. But there is a bug here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89159 , so it needs some workaround.

Comment: *" your code but it doesn't work"*, what error are you getting?

Comment: when I add data to the columns, it doesn't get updated in the console

Comment: hmmm.. Have you debugged? Do you have any data. Code is not the issue